# Spring JPA Criteria Builder wrong result when using PageImpl

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, hibernate-criteria

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring data in my project. For query data, I used criteria builder to add where conditions as well as order. Source code below:

```
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<TranxLog> query = builder.createQuery(TranxLog.class);
        Root r = query.from(TranxLog.class);
        Predicate predicate = builder.conjunction();
        predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(r.get("purchaseDate"), ParseUtils.strToDate(formModel.getSearchFromDate())));
        predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(r.get("purchaseDate"), ParseUtils.strToDate(formModel.getSearchToDate())));
        predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.equal(r.get("deleted"), "N"));
        predicate = builder.and(predicate, builder.equal(r.get("clientId"), user.getClientId()));
        query.where(predicate);
        query.orderBy(builder.desc(r.<Date>get("purchaseDate")), builder.asc(r.get("merchantId")),builder.asc(r.get("terminalId")),builder.asc(r.get("tranxLogId")));

        CriteriaQuery<TranxLog> select = query.select(query.from(TranxLog.class));
        TypedQuery<TranxLog> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(select);

        CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        countQuery.select(builder.count(countQuery.from(TranxLog.class)));
        Long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
        typedQuery.setFirstResult(page.getPageNumber() * page.getPageSize());
        typedQuery.setMaxResults(page.getPageSize());

        List<TranxLog> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
        return new PageImpl<TranxLog>(resultList, page, count);
```

**Here is hibernate query**

```
SELECT
            tranxlog1_.tranx_log_id AS tranx_log_id1_30_,
            tranxlog1_.account_id AS account_id2_30_,
            tranxlog1_.acq_iss AS acq_iss3_30_,
            tranxlog1_.acqbin AS acqbin4_30_
FROM
            tranx_log tranxlog0_,
            tranx_log tranxlog1_
        WHERE
                1 = 1
            AND
                tranxlog0_.purchase_date >=?
            AND
                tranxlog0_.purchase_date <=?
            AND
                tranxlog0_.deleted =?
            AND
                tranxlog0_.client_id =?
        ORDER BY
            tranxlog0_.purchase_date DESC,
            tranxlog0_.merchant_id ASC,
            tranxlog0_.terminal_id ASC,
            tranxlog0_.tranx_log_id ASC
```

Look at query, you'll see that select is from tranxlog1 but order by tranxlog0, so data result getting wrong order.

I don't know why it has `from tranxlog0_ and tranxlog1_` because if I return a List, it works perfect but Page has 2 entites and wrong order.

Any idea? Thanks so much.

Comment: Try removing `CriteriaQuery<TranxLog> select = query.select(query.from(TranxLog.class));` (or replacing it by  `CriteriaQuery<TranxLog> select = query.select(r);`). Also, don't use raw types. I would also use JPQL instead of Criteria, which would lead to much simpler, clearer, more maintainable code. Especially since your query is not dynamic at all, and isn't any safer than a JPQL one since you're not using the metamodel classes.

Comment: Well it works. Thanks so much.